# "was" as a past subjunctive

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood

I'd like to know whether "was" should be treated as a subjunctive in the following:

> a. If there were a 20-story office building without an elevator, those whose office **was** on the 18th floor would climb many steps each day.
>
> b. If there were someone who **was** able to speak over 500 languages at native levels, he would be considered a genius of some sort.

Here **was** is used to describe hypothetical situations and is considered correct even in Standard American English

I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question not long ago

Comment: No one really addressed, or rather solved, the core of the question.

Comment: The subjunctive form is directly controlled by the irrealis marker (_if_ or inversion); it’s not just ‘anything that describes a hypothetical situation’. Only the verb controlled by the irrealis marker is in the subjunctive, not any subsequent verbs in subsequent clauses.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly controlled"?

Comment: If "was" is not subjunctive, why wasn't "is" used instead?

Comment: I personally think that *who is* sounds better. However, best of all is if you remove *who was* altogether. There is no reason for it to be there. Just write *someone able to speak*. (I would make the first sentence read *those with offices on the 18th floor*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Whilst I agree with the second part of your comment, about omitting "who was" altogether, I cannot agree with your first part. Let's say there has just been a minor accident and no one is hurt. I might say "If there were someone who WAS injured we would need an ambulance". All of that happens in the present, but nonetheless I cannot grammatically use "is". I think it is what the grammarians here call "backshifting".

Comment: Backshifting into what?

Comment: @WS2 If an ambulance is required, it can only because somebody still **is** injured. It's no different than the present tense being optional in reported speech if the fact being reported is still true. *"Can I have your attention please. Is anyone hurt? If someone is injured, we need an ambulance. Is there anyone? No? Then we don't."*

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes. I agree with that, but we are dealing with the "if supposition clause" (for want of the correct technical term) here. Somebody is NOT injured. So we are saying "We should be glad things are not worse, because if someone WAS (at this very moment) injured, then rescue action would be necessary". You cannot possibly replace WAS with IS right there, can you? Or "Fortunately the sun's shining. If it WAS raining at this very moment, we would need an umbrella".

Comment: @ws2 Your formulations are not the same as in the question. When a relative pronoun is used to describe something, then the present tense can be used. *If it were raining, all of the people who don't have umbrellas would now be wet.* Present tense. *Didn't bring*, past tense, would also be fine. But you're not going to convince me that I can't use the present tense there—or that it doesn't actually sound better.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't disagree with your examples, but the OP's example b seems exactly like my "If someone were injured...". I don't believe it grammatical to say "If there were someone who IS able to speak 500 language, it would be phenomenal".  People undoubtedly say all sorts of things during the bustle of everyday conversation - I may have said it myself. But to my mind, to be correct, it has to be "was".

Answer (score -2):

In a comment, Janus Bahs Jacquet wrote:

> The subjunctive form is directly controlled by the irrealis marker (*if* or inversion); it’s not just ‘anything that describes a hypothetical situation’. Only the verb controlled by the irrealis marker is in the subjunctive, not any subsequent verbs in subsequent clauses.